# Update --strange interaction while probing circuit

Tags: oscillator, grounding, isolation, probe, decoupling

I'm encountering strange behavior from this Colpitts oscillator circuit when I probe what is an "isolated" output.  Probing an isolated output is causing another otherwise good output signal (also isolated via a buffer) to get distorted.  I've yet to understand how this interaction is occurring.

[image]

I breadboarded the circuit and the buffered sinewave output looks as expected when probed by itself (10X probe) as shown in the figure below in blue.

[image]

However, when I also probe the buffered (isolated) square wave drive signal, the sinewave output is significantly distorted as shown below.  The overshoot/ringing seen on the yellow trace goes away as expected if I reduce the length the ground clip,  so it is just an artifact of the probe set up.  The jagged blue trace seems to be "real".  The yellow trace is scaled at 5V/div, while the blue trace is at 1V/div.

[image]

It is strange that probing the output of U2 affects the output of U1 (as seen at the output of U3), since U2 is providing isolation and probing its output should not be loading U1.
On the board, I have 1nF decoupling caps on the comparator U1 as well as the unity gain buffers, and the +5V comes from a +5V regulator on the board whose input is decoupled with a 10uF in parallel with a 0.1nF cap. The grounding is not "great" since it is a simple bread board built on a vector board (as opposed to a copper clad board), although I've improved it with additional copper tape---I'm thinking this (inadequate grounding) may ultimately be the underlying cause of what I'm seeing, since the signal frequency is in the 10-15MHz range.

I thought the op-amps might be struggling to drive the ~15pF probe capacitance, but that doesn't gel with the fact that probing the sinewave output alone looks fine.  I need to monitor the supply while I probe the outputs to see if somehow the regulator is going out of regulation. Although I don't know why that would be, that makes more sense to me than anything else as to why the output at U3 would be affected by something on the output of U2 (again, perhaps grounding and insufficient decoupling are the underlying cause?).

I need to confirm this tomorrow, but I think that connecting the second probe's ground clip to the circuit ground begins distorting the sinewave output slightly.  Hanging the probe on the squarewave output signal is what ultimately distorts it to the level shown in the figure above. I ruled out some strange coupling between the probes by using probes connected to different o'scopes (although maybe I'm still creating a ground loop through the earth ground connection at the outlets).

Anyway, perhaps someone on here has experienced something similar to what I'm seeing and can shed some light on what may be happening.  I'd appreciate any input.

*** UPDATE ***
I now have a 2-layer board with all components on the top side, allowing for a solid ground plane on the  bottom layer as well as ground fill on the top layer.  Decoupling is done with a 10uF  in parallel with a .1nF cap on all the ICS, as well as a 100uF on the supply to the PCB.
At 1MHz, the circuit works as expected, and I can probe the outputs of U3 and U2 without any issues.  However, when I tune the resonator to 10MHz, I again see that probing the output of U2 distorts the the output of U3.  I can't tell if it is an artifact of the scope and probes (gnd lead inductance, etc), or if it is "real" .  In fact, U2 and U3 drive a light load to gnd, and there are test points accessible to monitor the ouptut signals. Just touching the testpoint on the output of U2 with tweezers (and me acting as a capacitor(?))is enough to completely distort the signal observed at U3.  The square wave output is unaffected, which suggests that perhaps what I'm seeing at U3 is not real --but I don't know to confirm this.
I broke the circuit between C2 and U3 (I have resistors in the actual circuit to divide signals, etc as needed) and injected a 10MHz sine wave with an function generator, and proved that it is not a bandwidth issue with U3 (and AD8061 opamp).  I am completely stumped.

Comment: Posting a picture of your physical circuit may be helpful. Does R3, U2, & U3 have bypass capacitors? Your at a frequency where lead lengths on your power supply circuitry can cause problems.

Comment: I think may have missed the bypass cap for R3, but i don't think that would cause the behavior I am seeing.  It only happens when I probe....

Comment: @jrive I loved the testing, reducing ground lead length. That's pretty telling. The ground lead has distributed inductance interacting with the probe capacitance of about 2 pF in this case I think, to cause ringing at frequencies determined by the L&C. It is completely unavoidable with long leads. Characterized as an added decaying sinusoid imposed on the waveform. Try making the ground lead *longer*! The interaction is interesting, but to me just suggests parasitics in the shared ground inside the scope. When the ringing frequency occurs outside the bandwidth limit you don't see it as much.

Comment: Yeah I think the root cause involves ground somehow. Oftentimes when I am connecting multiple scope probes I like to connect *only one ground* to maintain a nice star-ground (no ground loops) topology. At frequencies of 10-15MHz having only a single ground should be no big deal. Also, as you suggest, it would be a very telling test to connect *only the ground lead* of your second probe and see if that's what makes the crucial difference. I'd wager it is.